# How to update the Id of multiple td after Jquery Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a table which is like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight"
    id="tab_logic">

   </table>
```

I am adding rows which has multiple columns to the table like this

```html
for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    
    var htm = "";
    htm += "<tbody class='editrow'> <tr class='321'><td colspan='3' align='center'><p id='addrp"+i+"'><strong>Action Button "
      + i + " Properties</strong></p></td></tr>";
    htm += "<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addac"+i+"'><strong>Action</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpac"+i+"'>Action</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiac"
      + i
      + "' name ='addiac"
      + i
      + "' placeholder='Enter Action'</td> </tr>";
    htm += "<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addat"+i+"'><strong>Action Text</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpat"+i+"'>Action Text</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addiat"
      + i
      + "' name ='addiat"
      + i
      + "' placeholder='Enter Action Text'</td> </tr>";
    htm += "<tr class='123'><td align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addcc"+i+"'><strong>Color Code</strong></p></td><td class='text-danger' align='center' style='width:15%'><p id='addpcc"+i+"'>Color Code</p></td><td><input type ='text' class ='form-control' id='addicc"
      + i
      + "' name ='addicc"
      + i
      + "' placeholder='Enter Color Code'</td> </tr></tbody>";
    $('#tab_logic').append(htm);
   }
```

Further i am enabling the sorting of the rows of this table with the help of JQuery UI Sortable

```html
$("#tab_logic").sortable({
     items : ".editrow",
     helper : "clone",
     update : function() {
      reorder();
     }
    }).disableSelection();
```

After doing this i am running a function reorder in the update attribute  of the JQuery scrollable which will update the id of all the table columns . As every td element is different i need to be able to scroll through each one of them and get their id and update it .

to this my reorder function is like this

```html
function reorder() {
   var order = $("#tab_logic").find('td');
   alert(order);
   var size = order.size();
   alert(size);

   for (var i = 0; i < order.size(); i++) {
    var t = order[i].attr('id');
    alert(t);
   }
  }
```

But `var t = order[i].attr('id');` is not giving me the id of the td element to update . How do i get it

I have also tried using

```html
function reorder() {
   var order = $("#tab_logic").find('td');
   var order = $("#tab_logic td");
   alert(order.length);
   order.each(function(){
    var t = var t = $(this).children("p:last").attr('id');
    alert(t);
    
   });

  }
```

Comment: because the id is defined on the `p`-tag iside the `td`, not the `td` itself? btw, what's the point of an id that changes?

Comment: @Thomas the table is a part of a form that i submit to my controller in spring which updates the database  . So for that i need to update the id accordingly . Can you tell me how i can still get the id for the td in the for loop ?

Comment: Instead of updating the `id` client side, why don't you sent the items in the correct order and update the order change in backend? Updating `id` of an element is not usually done in frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of the `.each()`.

> Type: Function( Integer index, Element element )
>
> A function to execute for each matched element.

```
function reorder() {
  var order = $("#tab_logic").find('td');
  alert(order);
  var size = order.size();
  alert(size);

  order.each(function(k, v){
    console.log("TD #" + k + " ID: " + $(v).attr("id"));
    var t = $(v).attr('id');
      alert(t);
    }
  });
}
```